# Prefix route I want to create already exists as controllers

Tags: cakephp, controllers

I'm new to cakephp so go easy on me!

I have a table called promoters and users can be promoters.

I want to create a "promoters dashboard/control panel". To do this I wanted to create a prefix route of "promoters".

E.g. you go to http://mywebsite.com/promoters/events/add you get to the `promoter_add` function within `EventsController`.

So the problem is that I actually have a controller called `PromotersController` which I need for the `admin` users (e.g. http://mywebsite.com/admin/promoters/add).

I hope you're following.

So... my question is, will I just have to do what I think I'm going to have to do which is to create a different prefix route? Maybe call it `promos` or something?

Or can I create a prefix route of `promoters` and just have it override the controller named `PromotersController` if it needs to?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just add the promoters dashboard method to the PromotersController?

```
class PromotersController extends AppController {

  public function dashboard() {

  }

}
```

you can then visit:

```
/promoters/dashboard
```

Comment: Ah yes, sorry its very complicated to explain. Promoters will be editing events and such. So I want to be able to link from the dashboard to /promoters/events and show them a list of events and let them edit their events... etc. :) So I want /events to list all the events for normal users to see and then /promoters/events to display the promoters_index() action in the EventsController (which would list that promoter's events with options to edit/delete/add etc).

Comment: Ok, how about making the default /events/index work the same for everyone and then make /events/promoters your index for promoters?

You could even put a test in /events/index to check if the user is a promoter and redirect them to /events/promoters

Comment: Hmm, sounds a bit complicated. I'd rather use the built in functions properly. I'll just change the prefix to dashboard. :) I'll mark yours as the answer however as it may give some other people some ideas :)